# PHP/MYSQLI - How to check if this query is possible, if so show error (see example)

Tags: php, if-statement, mysqli

I am learning some myqli and would like to make a simple check.

Basically, A user will enter their email addess then submit a form, if the email address is already contained in a certain mysql table, then the script must stop with an error.

This is my example:

```
$userEmail = sanitize($_POST['specials']);          
// Check to see if email already exists, if not proceed
if ($stmt = $link->prepare("SELECT email FROM specials WHERE email=$userEmail"))
{
    $specialsErrorFocus = 'autofocus="autofocus"';
    $specialsInfo = 'This email address: $userEmail, is already in our database.';
    include "$docRoot/html/shop/home.html.php";
    exit();
}
```

This code does not do as I have intended it to as described.

Could someone please explain where I am going wrong with this, or possibly offer a better solution for this task.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to execute the query first, as simply preparing the statement is not sufficient. See the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) as it is a multi stage process.

First, you prepare the statement:

```
$stmt = $link->prepare("SELECT `email` FROM `specials` WHERE `email` = ?")
if (!$stmt) {
   echo $link->errno . " : " . $link->error;
}
```

Next, bind the parameters:

```
if (!$stmt->bind_param("s", $userEmail)) {
    echo $stmt->errno . " : " . $stmt->error;
}
```

Finally, execute the query:

```
if (!$stmt->execute()) {
    echo $stmt->errno . " : " . $stmt->error;
}
```

Get the results:

```
$stmt->store_result();

if ($stmt->num_rows) {

   # Email exists
}
```

Comment: Hi, `if (!$stmt)` produces a syntax error... o i see you left out a `;`

Comment: Please explain how the input `($userEmail)` is bound into this? What is the "s"?

Comment: See the documentation for [`bind_param`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php)

Answer (score 1):

Prepare does not execute the statement. You can use [mysql::query](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) to execute the statement.

Your Example would become:

```
$result = $link->query("SELECT email FROM specials WHERE email=$userEmail");    
if ( $result ) {
    if ( $result->num_rows > 0 ) {
        $specialsErrorFocus = 'autofocus="autofocus"';
        $specialsInfo = 'This email address: $userEmail, is already in our database.';
        include "$docRoot/html/shop/home.html.php";
        exit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the input, but the code that you have provided does not give the correct result. The script is proceeding when in fact it should be halted, e.g. the email does exist in the database.

Comment: Amended example: missing if num_rows > 0 check